# Mean value of multikey dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas

I want to find the mean price of an item in a dictionary that have pairs of item,shop as key and the price as value

example dictionary

```
{('item1', 'shop1'): 40,
('item2', 'shop2'): 14,
('item1', 'shop3'): 55,
```

for example i want to find the mean price of item1. Is it possible with a multikey dictionary or should i change it? Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: You want to find the mean price of an item across all shops?

Comment: i want the mean of all items

Comment: why is this labelled pandas?

Comment: because i am using pandas

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. Not sure if this is the right data structure to your problem but you can do it like this.

First you select all the keys with the item you want, here I'm selecting `'item1'`:

```
interesting_keys = filter(lambda k: k[0] == 'item1', a.keys())
```

Now you can sum all those elements and divide by the number of elements.

```
result = sum([a[k] for k in interesting_keys])/len(interesting_keys)
```

If you want to create a new dictionary reduced to one element per key followed by the mean, you may do something that looks like this:

```
def group_prices(prices):
    grouped_prices = {}
    number_items = {}
    for k, v in prices.iteritems():
        grouped_prices[k[0]] = grouped_prices.get(k[0], 0) + v
        number_items[k[0]] = number_items.get(k[0], 0) + 1
    return {k:v/number_items[k] for (k,v) in grouped_prices.iteritems()}
```

Comment: And if i want it for all the items?

Comment: What do you mean? Like if you want to combine the information for every possible item?

Comment: Yes, not only for item1 but for every item and create a new data structure with the mean for every item

Comment: I added a function that may help you

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Pandas DataFrame using `nested lists`. You can then use Pandas `groupby` to get the `mean` you're looking for.

```
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.DataFrame([['item1', 'shop1', 40],
    ['item2', 'shop2', 14],
    ['item1', 'shop3', 55]], columns=('item', 'shop', 'price'))
    df
        item    shop    price
    0   item1   shop1   40
    1   item2   shop2   14
    2   item1   shop3   55
    result_mean = df.groupby('item')['price'].mean()
    result_mean
    item
    item1    47.5
    item2    14.0
    Name: price, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have already tried it with dataframe but i want to use it to do some calculations it is pretty slow. My original data structure is a dictionary and i thought it would be better and faster to do the calculations using a dictionary

Comment: @mnmbs You have `pandas` tag in your question, therefore, I provided a pandas answer. btw: `pandas` is not slow.

Comment: Yes but i also say that i am using dictionary in my question. But thats ok. Thanks again

P.S. Believe me if you have file with 2M rows it can be slow

Answer (score 1):

Since this is labelled pandas... If you make this a pandas Series you can groupby the 0th level:

```
In [11]: d = {('item1', 'shop1'): 40, ('item2', 'shop2'): 14,('item1', 'shop3'): 55}

In [12]: s = pd.Series(d)

In [13]: s
Out[13]:
item1  shop1    40
       shop3    55
item2  shop2    14
dtype: int64

In [14]: s.groupby(level=0).mean()
Out[14]:
item1    47.5
item2    14.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: I have already tried it with series and dataframes but i thought that since i want to use the mean data structure to subtract from my original dictionary it would be better if it is a dictionary too. But i can be wrong..i am still learning :)

Comment: How can i then compare it with the dictionary?

Comment: If you have 2M rows ditch the dictionary and us pandas read_csv or something, dictionary groupby is going to be O(N), once you've constructed the groupby pandas groupby/mean will be more like O(1).

Comment: I tried that but when i want to subtract the mean from the original values ( one dataframe from another) i get a dead kernel every time. Thats why i gave up on dataframes

Comment: Please ask a question about that specific error (the dead kernel one). 2M is not a lot, pandas should handle it easily. This question by itself suffers from the [XY-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this using pandas DataFrame:

```
# create a test dict like the question
my_dict = dict(zip([
    ('item'+str(i), 'shop'+str(k)) for i in range(5) for k in range(3)],
    [random.randint(1,10) for j in range(15)
    ]))

# create a DataFrame wih MultiIndex
ndx=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(my_dict.keys()), names=['item','shop'])
df = pd.DataFrame(list(my_dict.values()), index=ndx, columns=['price'])
print('\n', df)

# reset index and use groupby to get means
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
item_mean = df.groupby('item').mean()
print('\n',item_mean)

              price
item  shop        
item3 shop0      5
      shop2      3
item1 shop0      4
item3 shop1      7
item4 shop0      7
item0 shop0     10
item2 shop1      3
      shop0      2
item1 shop1     10
item4 shop2      5
      shop1      3
item1 shop2      2
item0 shop1      1
      shop2      8
item2 shop2      7

           price
item           
item0  6.333333
item1  5.333333
item2  4.000000
item3  5.000000
item4  5.000000
```